# Haskell Typeclasses with parametric types

Tags: haskell, interface, typeclass, abstraction

I want to define a specific functor as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data ValOrError a b = Val a | Error b

class MF c a b where
  mcons :: a -> c -> c
  merr :: b -> c
  mhead :: c -> ValOrError a b
  mtail :: c -> ValOrError c b
```

I want that my typeclass `MF` on type `c` has type parameters `a` and `b`. I tried to define a filter function on such data structure as follows:

```
mfilter f e =
  let h = mhead e in
  let t = mtail e in
  case h of
    Error b -> e
    Val a -> case (f a) of
      True -> case t of
        Error d -> mcons a (merr d)
        Val b -> mcons a (mfilter f b)
      False -> case t of
        Error d -> merr d
        Val b -> mfilter f b
```

But I got the following error:

> haskell.hs:24:1:
>
> ```
> Could not deduce (MF c a2 b3)
>   arising from the ambiguity check for ‘mfilter’
> from the context (MF c a5 b6,
>                   MF c a4 b5,
>                   MF c a4 b4,
>                   MF c a4 b,
>                   MF c a3 b6,
>                   MF c a b6)
>   bound by the inferred type for ‘mfilter’:
>              (MF c a5 b6, MF c a4 b5, MF c a4 b4,
>               MF c a4 b, MF c a3 b6, MF c a b6) =>
>              (a4 -> Bool) -> c -> c
>   at haskell.hs:(24,1)-(35,28)
> The type variables ‘a2’, ‘b3’ are ambiguous
> When checking that ‘mfilter’
>   has the inferred type ‘forall b c a b1 a1 a2 b2 a3 b3.
>                          (MF c a3 b3, MF c a2 b2, MF c a2 b1,
>                           MF c a2 b, MF c a1 b3, MF c a b3) =>
>                          (a2 -> Bool) -> c -> c’
> Probable cause: the inferred type is ambiguous
> ```

I'm wondering if there is a better way in haskell to state that the type `c` always has `a` and `b` as type parameters. Using a Java-like syntax:

```
public interface MF<A,B> {
   MF<A,B> mcons(A head, MF<A,B> tail);
   MF<A,B> merr(B error);
   ValOrError<A,B> head(MF<A,B> e);
   ValOrError<MF<A,B>,B> tail(MF<A,B> e);
}
```

Plus, on the other hand, the filter function should have a type:

```
mfilter :: (a -> Bool) -> MF c a b -> MF c a b
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most direct way to do this, starting from your code, would be to add *functional dependencies* to your type class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
class MF c a b | c -> a, c -> b where
  ...
```

This essentially just tells the compiler that the type information of `a` and `b` is already contained in `c` (and can thus be extracted at the call site, so `a2`, `b3` etc. won't be ambiguous). How exactly to extract this information can be determined be GHC when you define an `instance MF`. Though usually this works quite well, I find it a bit questionable why you want to do it this way: if `c` always has the form `X a b` anyway (and `X` is a proper `data`-type-function that can be partially applied), then why even mention `a` and `b` in the class head? They're basically redundant. Why not just give the class a single parameter (of kind `Type -> Type -> Type`) which can then be *applied* to `a` and `b`?

```
class MF x where
  mcons :: a -> x a b -> x a b
  merr :: b -> x a b
  mhead :: x a b -> ValOrError a b
  mtail :: x a b -> ValOrError (x a b) b
```

Alternatively, if you really want `c` to have kind `Type` (which can indeed make sense!), I should recommend stowing the `a` and `b` types in the *class definition* as type families:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
class MF c where
  type ValType c :: *
  type ErrType c :: *
  mcons :: ValType c -> c -> c
  merr :: ErrType c -> c
  mhead :: c -> ValOrError (ValType c) (ErrType c)
  mtail :: c -> ValOrError c (ErrType c)
```

This is basically equivalent to the `TypeFamilies` solution, but gives a more explicit, less cryptic (albeit also rather more verbose) interface.

Comment: I have a question concerning the last solution, which I prefer the most. If I have the following data

`data MemoryMonad a b =  Lift b | Guard b | Elem a (MemoryMonad a b)`

how can I make it an instance of this typeclass?

Comment: @jackb `instance MF (MemoryMonad a b) where type ValType (MemoryMonad a b) = a; type ErrType (MemoryMonad a b) = b`